# Re-start animation if message is sent again?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

REWRITTEN: Lets just say I have it where my animation plays when I press the space bar. How can I have it where the animation plays from start every time I press the space bar rather than continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the continue option on the action actuator and put the script between the sensor and the action actuator :

- when the sensor send a pulse the script will be triggered
- if there is action being played on layer 0 the script will stop stop it
- the script passes the pulse to the actuator

---

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

if own.isPlayingAction(0):
    own.stopAction(0)
cont.activate("Action")
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: Doesn't do what I asked. I need it where every time I press space it will play the action BUT when you press space and it is already in the action it will reset.

Comment: do you mean reset it ( stop it ) or (stop it and start again ) ?

Comment: 1st time you press: start; 2nd time (if animation is still going on): stop and start again; 2nd time (if animation is done): start

Comment: that's exactly what it does, did you try it ?

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't do it the way I just asked. Your script makes it where when I am holding space bar the animation will be playing, and when I let go the animation just stops and doesn't play.

Comment: what did you set the action playback ?

Comment: "play" - action playback

Comment: set it to flipper

Comment: "if own.isPlayingAction(0):" - that line interests me, is there a way I can have a property be toggled to true when the animation is playing but false when not?

Comment: Oh, flipper. OK

Comment: I got it to work in a little different way, but problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: there is something for your other question but it has a problem so i didn't post , you can use `(own.getLinearVelocity(False)).magnitude` to detect if object is moving (but it doesn't work while action playing!)

Comment: also what is the other way ?

Comment: Oh, I did it where it updates every tick, and when the message to do the animation is played, a boolean is true. When it is not being sent, it is false. When it is true, with pulse, and the setup you told me. If I just do the space bar itself it wont work.

Comment: Also, does this affect any other animations because my others are having problems.

Comment: yes all actions on layer 0 will stop !

Comment: Oh this is bad. By layers, is that just a way to organize animations? Is it layers in the scene? How would I make it where ONLY this animation does this? Would I just make it in another layer and edit the script? Help me please.

Comment: just put it on another layer and change the number 0 , layer are there so you can have multiple action playing and blend them